# Threads: Invoke cause an InvalidCastException

Tags: vb.net, iasyncresult

I want to return the text of a textbox. This worked. But calling the function with the before determined parameter cause an InvalidCastException. Visual Studio says that converting from IAsyncResult to FileInfo (searchEnginePower returns this) could cause runtime errors.

```
    Dim result As IAsyncResult = Me.BeginInvoke(Function() As String
                                                    Return PropABCtool.PropTextbox1
                                                End Function)
    Dim a As FileInfo = Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() PropABCtool_.PropCar.searchEnginePower(Me.EndInvoke(result)))
    If a IsNot Nothing And a.Exists Then 
    ...

    End If
```

How can I solve the exception?

Comment: If you want to get the result of the invoked method there and then, just call `Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided all the relevant information but, from what I can tell, you should be doing this:

```
Dim a As FileInfo = Me.Invoke(Function() PropABCtool_.PropCar.searchEnginePower(PropABCtool.PropTextbox1))
```